# How to list available cookies in Hapi.js?

Tags: cookies, hapi

In my Hapi server I want to delete all cookies that start with "dev_". In order to do so, I need to know what cookies are set.

The documentation tell me I can

- Get a cookie `const myCookie = request.state.dev_cookie1`
- Set a cookie `response.state("dev_cookie1", {})`
- Delete a cookie `response.unstate("dev_cookie1")`

But how can I list all the cookies so I can delete them?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this solution, simpler than I thought, really.

```js
     Object.keys(request.state).forEach(cookieName => {
        if (cookieName.startsWith("dev_")) {
          resp.unstate(cookieName)
        }
      })
```